# Elastic Beanstalk Database Pool Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, puma

I recently decided to switch from Heroku to deploying directly to AWS through their Elastic Beanstalk service - hope my terminology is right still figuring out AWS. I have the app running here on EB and here on Heroku (this is a free Heroku app so may take 10ish seconds to start). The app runs perfectly on Heroku, but on EB it only sometimes loads. Maybe like 1 out of 4 times, I get a `Internal Server Error`. My database pool it set to 5, and if I scale it up to 25 it works, but I am the only one using the website, and from what I hear 5 should be plenty.

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/website.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/cucumber-tests.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  pool: 5
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Side note, after I figure out why pool 5 is not enough, how to I make the pool size scalable? From what I can tell there is not a `RDS_POOL` variable. Is there a way I can scale it based on the number of users?

Here is my error log for puma:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/puma/puma.log
-------------------------------------
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:182:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2013:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `block in call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1787:in `synchronize'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:232:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-03-10 03:43:14 - ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were i
n use:
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `loop'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `wait_poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:154:in `internal_poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:278:in `internal_poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `block in poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:158:in `synchronize'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `poll'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:717:in `acquire_connection'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:490:in `checkout'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:883:in `retrieve_connection'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:96:in `initialize'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:399:in `new'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:399:in `construct_join_dependency'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:321:in `exists?'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `exists?'
        app/views/index.erb:66:in `block in singleton class'
app/views/index.erb:-6:in `instance_eval'
        app/views/index.erb:-6:in `singleton class'
        app/views/index.erb:-8:in `__tilt_47116404404940'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.6/lib/tilt/template.rb:161:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.6/lib/tilt/template.rb:161:in `evaluate'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.6/lib/tilt/template.rb:100:in `render'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:823:in `render'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:667:in `erb'
        /var/app/current/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:60:in `block in <class:ApplicationController>'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `block in compile!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:994:in `route_eval'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1015:in `block in process_route'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `catch'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `process_route'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:973:in `block in route!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `each'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `route!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1085:in `block in dispatch!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1082:in `dispatch!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `block in call!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `call!'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:895:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:182:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2013:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `block in call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1787:in `synchronize'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/deflater.rb:35:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:232:in `call'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
        /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.7.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**- All the code is opensource and can be found [here](https://github.com/Christianjuth/whatbywhat) -**

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE: I can not let this app be down any longer. I am setting the pool to 25 for now. I have also changed the DSN so the [old app can be found here](https://heroku.whatbywhat.com), and [the new app here](https://beta.whatbywhat.com)**

**UPDATE 2: I am adding the `ruby-on-rails` tag to gain more traction since this issue is related, but the project is using Sinatra not Rails.**

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your code needs to be reduced to the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem and be in the question itself not in a link. Your tags/keywords are not primary keywords. I'd recommend replacing one with Ruby and another with Rails if you want a lot of eyes to see the question. Also, don't use salutations ("hi"), valedictions ("thank you") or signatures. SO isn't a discussion list it's an online reference book. Finally, "edit" and "update" tags are undesirable. Incorporate the changed text into the question as if it'd been there initially. We can see what changed when.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Puma—a threaded web server. Puma starts multiple ruby threads in one process to handle requests concurrently. The number of threads puma is creating might be higher than the number of database connections you have in your pool (defined in `database.yml`).

ActiveRecord naturally keeps a pool of database connections open and creates new connections lazily. Your `database.yml` looks like you have the max pool size set to 5. This means ActiveRecord will not create more than 5 connections in the pool and will only create a new connection when the pool is empty and a connection is asked for.

I couldn't find a puma config in your repository, so I'll assume puma is using the defaults. [The default max threads for Puma is 16](https://github.com/puma/puma#thread-pool). This might indicate your webserver has 16 threads running (worst-case scenario) and every thread after the 5th is waiting for a connection to be returned to the pool to use. That's 5 connections shared amongst your 16 threads. As a best practice, I always make sure the database pool size is `n+1` where `n` is the maximum number of threads that will run in my application.

I cannot guess why the issue does not also exist in heroku.